# Using tank_auth with multi type user and HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, tankauth

Using Tank Auth for first time along with HMVC. In my application there are 2 type of user one is say student and another is institute.
 I created two modules for each user type and separated the tank auth library , both user's registration, login and tables are different from each other.

Now if I try to add any other page which is common to both users like home page, Which library should be used.
  I know there must be better solution to handle multiple user problem.
Please let me know where I'm doing wrong. And what should I do to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there's a better way to handle this.  Duplicating your user / registration system is the wrong way to go.

You'll need to modify TankAuth to include a user type column, and then check for that user type.  I'd suggest a new column in the 'users' table for 'user_role':

https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth/blob/master/schema.sql

You could handle the user_type as either an int or enum.  I'd lean towards int since enum is harder to change later.  You could also add a new table for user_roles but I usually just store these in a config file.

Once the schema is altered, you'll need to add a reference to the new column (along with possible options) in the Tank_Auth code.  You'll need to include it in creation, update (data is passed to model from the tank auth controller: controllers/auth.php)  and lookup functions.  I would add a lookup by user_role as well to the tank_auth model (application / models / tank_auth / users.php):

```
function get_user_by_role($role)
{
$this->db->where('LOWER(user_role)=', strtolower($role));

$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) return $query->row();
return NULL;
}
```

Lastly, you'll want to set the user role to session on login so that you can track the user type (and what content / functionality they have access to).

I've used Tank_Auth myself for several projects.

Comment: Your solution sounds good, but before accepting will wait for others.

Answer (score 0):

building on what calvin said, codeigniter does a good job a securing your application, tank auth will verify them, however you need different user levels, this usually falls under permissions.  Your job as a developer is to make sure codeigniter does it's security checks via CSRF & XSS( I would suggest you do this in each validaton rule, rather than globally, especially If your admins need to add any tags not allowed suc as "script").  you can see how I personally setup my controllers regardless of my Auth library [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523097/codeigniter-ion-auth-extending-admin-controller/8546607#8546607)

You need to have a row in your users table called "permissions" which is either a serialized array or json encoded, or you can do a google search on permission bitmasking, which requires an int field